# How can I read -mdoc /-mandoc man pages using `M-x woman`?

Tags: package

I have been successfully using `M-x woman` to access the linux `man` pages.

But when I tried to read the `tmux` manpage using `woman`, it did not work.
But `M-: (man "tmux")` works.

Using `woman` to access `tmux` man page gave me this error

> WoMan formatting buffer...
>
> woman-decode-region: WoMan can only format man pages written with the usual `-man' macros

and the man page shows up without any formatting as below:

```
.Dd $Mdocdate: March 25 2013 $
.Dt TMUX 1
.Os
.Sh NAME
.Nm tmux
.Nd terminal multiplexer
.Sh SYNOPSIS
.Nm tmux
.Bk -words
.Op Fl 2CluvV
.Op Fl c Ar shell-command
.Op Fl f Ar file
.Op Fl L Ar socket-name
- snip -
```

Later I learned that that's because the tmux man pages are generated using a [new `-mdoc` macro](https://bitbucket.org/gdamore/less-fork/issue/4/use-mdoc-macros-for-manpages) instead of the `-man` macro.

Is there a way to read `-mdoc` generated man pages using `woman`? I prefer that vs doing `M-x man` because the cache generation for `completing-read` is much faster and accurate with `M-x woman`.

*I am using the latest versions of tmux (2.1+) and emacs (25.0+) from the master branches of their gits.*

Comment: `M-x man RET tmux(1)` works here on 24.5

Comment: I am on the latest git master of both emacs and tmux. One of two things could have happened: tmux moved from -man to -mdoc for its man pages or some bug in emacs? **Update**: I see the same problem with tmux 1.9a man page opened using emacs 24.5 `woman`.

Comment: @wasamasa Apologies.. `M-: (man "tmux")` does work for me, but not `woman`. I will delete this question altogether in a minute. The issue for me is that `completing-read` is not showing me `tmux` even though the `$MANPATH` is set correctly. But `M-:` approach works.